# Get Complete String after specific word using regex

Tags: regex, wordpress, redirect

I want to redirect 1000 of URL'S using wordpress Redirection plugin with regex.

Here is the my URL

http://domain.com/blog/tag/washington/

need to redirect on

http://domain.com/tag/washington/

Comment: Search for `/tag/` in your URL and get remaining part.

Comment: Im trying to handle this with this regex.
Source: /blog/(.*)
target: /$1
but its still blog word in the string.